# Rounding off not working in jQuery wiht input name parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a simple program, where if use enters any number, it must on keyup be changed to a whole number even if he enters decimal values. I dont know why program not running!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" /> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[name="input1"]').keyup(function(){
                $(this).val() = Math.round($(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
    Number: <input type="text" name="input1" /> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: move the single ' : `$('input[name="input1"]')`

Comment: was a typo. still not able to get rounded off values!

Comment: And `$(this).val(Math.round($(this).val()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue** **you're going to face with** `keyup` **is that, your function will be fired after typing the first digit.**
You can see that problem [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4wis2jvQDZ0isBDkiu4B?p=preview)

Use the `blur` function instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[name="input1"]').blur(function(){
              $(this).val( Math.round($(this).val()));
            });
        });
```

Here is a working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LlunqJRGMO97oqdqY8Y4?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

set the `val` like this:-

```
$('input[name="input1"]').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val(Math.round($(this).val()));
});
```

though `blur` could be better to allow for a decimal, to then round on exit.

**blur example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="input1"]').blur(function() {
    $(this).val(Math.round($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Number:
<input type="text" name="input1" />
```

Comment: Was a typo. still not getting the rounded off values on keyup!

Comment: Are you sure about `$(this).val() = Math.round($(this).val());` ? I doubt ;(

Comment: `$(this).val(Math.round($(this).val()));`

Comment: `$(this).val() = Math.round($(this).val())` is an invalid assignment

Comment: @RayonDabre - still not getting it ;(

Comment: What output are you expecting? Just an integer (1, 2, 5, 10) or a float (1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 10.00)?

Comment: @RayonDabre I spotted the first issue and went with it, not realising the actual problem before submitting. silly me.

Comment: @BenG, It happens mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can do also like this.
press [TAB] after entering the number.

```js
    $("#Number").blur(function(){
       $(this).val(Math.round($(this).val()));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number: <input type="text" name="input1" id="Number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing number do you write it with "," like this "1,6" or with "." like this "1.6"? In 1st example there will be a problem with NaN value (no a number) so you have to make a exception for that.